# Equivalence of numberOfTouchesRequired (UIGestureRecognizer) for Android?

Tags: android, gesture, ontouchlistener

In iOS, we've the property numberOfTouchesRequired in UIGestureRecognizer class. 
Its meaning is: the number of fingers required to tap for the gesture to be recognized.

```
@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger numberOfTouchesRequired
```

I want to detect when the user taps with two fingers at the same time in different parts of the screen.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works a bit differently in Android, but you can get the same feature.
You just need to override `onTouchEvent(motionEvent)`

There, you will be able to manipulate the event variable that contains among other things the number of fingers on the screen (`event.getPointerCount()` )

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is there is no way to do this out of the box with the android gesture recognition API and you will have to roll your own.

The basic detectors you get with android sdk are GestureDetector and ScaleGestureDetector.

If you are totally new to android check out the official tutorial/training on Gestures here: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html

The GestureDetector class detects a buch of typical gesture like tap, long press, swipe, fling  (see SimpleOnGestureListener interface) but unlike UIGestureRecogniser in iOS it is not flexible in configuring the recognizers or specifying dependencies between them. Basically the recognizer is a black box and all you get is the callback action method. You can't really configure it with "require fail" or "recognize simultaneously" contraints or even basic configuration like number of fingers.

Conceptually to implement a 2 finger tap is not that hard. You have to make sure the two fingers are close to each other (some threshold) and the touch times (for both down and up event) are very close (some other threshold).

Check out the tutorial above and you should have enough detail to implement on on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Lib Which has replicated the iOS gesture lib [Link](https://git.corp.adobe.com/AdobeMobileCodeShare/AndroidUIGestureRecognizer)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an opensource library I'm working on which replicates the iOS UIGestureRecognizer framework: https://github.com/sephiroth74/AndroidUIGestureRecognizer